# Quasi-complete separation

Tags: logistic, data-visualization, separation

I have a question regarding quasi-complete separated data.

One example of quasi-complete separation is a dataset, where all x < 2 have y=1, all x > 2 have y=0 and some x=2 have y=0 and some x=2 have y=1.

I have a dataset with kind of the following situation:
for all x < 2 y=0, for all x > 5 y=1.
In the rage x=2 to x=5 y is sometimes zero and sometimes one.

Is this a case of quasi-complete separation as well?

Does is matter for logistic regression if the range of x=2 to x=5, where y varies, is small?

An example how my data look like:

[image]

Comment: Here you can find an answer: [What is complete or quasi-complete separation in logistic/probit regression and how do we deal with them?](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/). Looking at your plot I wouldn't name it _quasi separated_ since you have a lot of observation which are not clearly defined 0 or 1 during a wide range of the predictor.

Answer (score 1):

Your textual description ("for all x < 2 y=0, for all x > 5 y=1. In the rage x=2 to x=5 y is sometimes zero and sometimes one") does not match your figure.  All data displayed in the figure have x<2, and many have y=1.  Nonetheless, neither your textual description nor the figure have separation or quasi separation.  For both your description and the figure, the data where y=0 and where y=1 overlap.  Logistic regression will have no problems with these data.